# How to extract data from this .mol2 file using python?

Tags: python, linux, file, dataframe, command-line

I'm doing some work with a .mol2 file (molecular structure file). In this file of mine, I have a number of molecules and there are some properties listed in the header of each file. How can I extract the info in the headers and create a table or csv file with all the data (properties as table column headers and each molecule name as a row header)? The file format for one molecule is shown in the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXRWs.png) image. To reiterate, I have a large file containing over 850,000 of these "files"—all in this format. Ideally, the script would be run using a python script executed in the command line, but if you know of another way to do (Linux?) so please feel free to share.

Thanks!!

Comment: Apparently Pandas module has a method to extract dataframe from a mol2 file. Does it help in your case? http://rasbt.github.io/biopandas/tutorials/Working_with_MOL2_Structures_in_DataFrames/

Comment: well while this is great for extracting info about the atoms, it doesn't help with extracting info from the headers (Set off by ##) which is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def get_data_dict(file_path: str, to_replace:str="##########") -> dict:
    """get data headers from a mol2 file (assumes header lines start with `to_replace`)
    :parameter
        - file_path:
          path to the file of interest
        - to_replace:
          the 'marker' that specifies the header
    :return
        - data_dict
          dict containing the header parts as keys and their values as value
    """
    data_dict = {}
    # open and read file until all header info is read
    with open(file_path, "r") as mol2_file:
        for line in mol2_file:
            # contains header info
            if line.startswith(to_replace):
                key = None
                value = None
                for i in line.split(":"):
                    i = i.strip()
                    if to_replace in i:
                        key = i.replace(to_replace, "").strip()
                    else:
                        value = i
                data_dict[key] = [value]
            # header ended
            else:
                return data_dict


all_data = pd.DataFrame()
# path to the directory containing all files
parent_path = "/PARENT/PATH"
for file in os.listdir(parent_path):
    data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(get_data_dict(os.path.join(parent_path, file)))
    all_data = pd.concat([all_data, data_df])
```

This saves all headers in a pandas DataFrame which you then can manipulate to your liking (e.g. save as csv or do something else).
For people coming here to find a solution how to parse a mol2 file in general you can do this with [biopandas](https://biopandas.github.io/biopandas/tutorials/Working_with_MOL2_Structures_in_DataFrames/#loading-mol2-files).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [read_mol2](https://pdbx2df.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#read-a-mol2-file) in the [pdbx2df](https://github.com/Ruibin-Liu/pdbx2df) package to read the header lines into a DataFrame.

```py
from pdbx2df import read_mol2
header_df = read_mol2('exrws.mol2', ['HEADER'])['HEADER']
print(header_df)
```

I only extracted the first two lines from the image and we get:

```
                  Name    HA_RMSDs
0  ZINC000034847145_10  -1000.0000
```